# Reorganize an array by 'id' index of nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>7 [name]=foo) [1]=>Array([id]=>10 [name]=bar) [2]=>Array([id]=>15 [name]=baz))
```

Each index contains an another array with various elements including an 'id'. I would like to "go up" a level, such that my top-level array is indexed by the ID element of the corresponding nested arrays, but that index still contains an array with all of the elements that were in the sub arrays?

In other words, how can I use PHP to turn the above array into this:

```
Array([7]=>Array([id]=>7 [name]=foo) [10]=>Array([id]=>10 [name]=bar) [15]=>Array([id]=>15 [name]=baz))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern, supported versions of PHP, this whole task can be achieved with `array_column()` alone.

Using `null` as the second parameter will leave the rows unchanged.

Using `id` as the 3rd parameter will assign those columnar values as the new first level keys.  Be aware that if these columnar values are not unique, subsequently encountered duplicates will overwrite previously encountered rows with the same `id` value -- this is because keys cannot be duplicates on a given level in an array.

DO NOT bother calling `array_combine()`, it is simply unnecessary/indirect.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7PZQn))

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'foo'],
    ['id' => 10, 'name' => 'bar'],
    ['id' => 15, 'name' => 'baz'],
];

var_export(
    array_column($array, null, 'id')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'name' => 'foo',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'id' => 10,
    'name' => 'bar',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'id' => 15,
    'name' => 'baz',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked this 10 years ago and I'm not really in a position now to evaluate this answer vs the original accepted answer. But I'd like to update the accepted answer in case others stumble upon this question. Why is array_combine() unnecessary/indirect?

Comment: Simply because the whole task can be done with one native function call.  This means the input array is only iterated once instead of twice.  Looping or mapping the data first to isolate one column of data, then iterating the data again to combine the two data sets.  This way is more concise, more efficient, and is the most modern technique.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do here is extract the ids from each sub-array in your input. If you have these as an array of ids, you are just an [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) call away from re-indexing your original array to use these ids as the keys.

You can produce such an array of ids using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which leads to:

```
// input data
$array = array(array('id' => '7', 'name' => 'foo'),array('id' => 10, 'name' => 'bar'));

// extract ids from the input array
$ids = array_map(function($arr) { return $arr['id']; }, $array);

// "reindex" original array using ids as array keys, keep original values
$result = array_combine($ids, $array);

print_r($result);
```

The syntax I 've used for the anonymous function (first argument to `array_map`) requires PHP >= 5.3, but you can achieve the same (although a bit less conveniently) with `create_function` in any PHP version you 'd not be ashamed of using.

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kwdKxb)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $newArray = array();
 foreach($oldArray as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$value['id']] = $value;
 }
```

Comment: +1 for the "low-tech" alternative, which is always good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.5.0, you can shorten the code by using [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) instead of `array_map()`.

```
$result = array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), $array);
```

Comment: https://eddmann.com/posts/an-array-column-re-indexing-trick-in-php/